# is it possible to project a shapefile to a raster's custom projection with command line gdal/ogr?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ogr, command-line

I have a raster with a user defined sinusoidal projection and a shapefile in lat/lng coordinates (I believe this is called 'unprojected'?).  I'd like to use ogr/gdal's command line utilities to project the shapefile into the raster's custom projection.

I see that `ogr2ogr` has a `t_srs` flag that if I had an EPSG code, I could use to project the shapefile into that local projection.  However, I am unsure what to do with my custom raster projection.

Per a comment below, this is the projection info from `gdalinfo`

```
Coordinate System is:
LOCAL_CS["SINUSOIDAL",
    UNIT["METERS",1]]
Origin = (-8895140.844619400799274,1111950.484813591465354)
Pixel Size = (463.312713623046989,-463.312713623046989)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-8895140.845, 1111950.485) 
Lower Left  (-8895140.845,-4448265.391) 
Upper Right (-2222974.456, 1111950.485) 
Lower Right (-2222974.456,-4448265.391) 
Center      (-5559057.650,-1668157.453)
```

Comment: by unprojected, if you mean there is no projection defined you would need to define it. It is not possible for it to exist without coordinates, and those coordinates are in some projection. please edit question with further information.

Comment: Just edited the question.  By unprojected I meant that the shapefile was in raw lat/lng coordinates. Is that how I should refer to it?

Comment: bit of a misnomer. Not sure if I even use it correctly.  unprojected - I consider a shape file that is normally in lat lon but there is no prj file. (assumed) but then you have to guess which dataum.  if there is a prj and it is lat lon - I call that wgs84 if the datum is gcs and nad83 if the datum is nad83. often uprojected is used (possibly incorrectly) as - the data is in a plane crs but has no prj with it.

Comment: What is the definition of the user defined sinusoidal projection ($ gdalinfo raster_file)

Comment: @Hermann I added the dump from the gdalinfo.  Can I use that directly in ogr2ogr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lat/lon extents of the raster are around

longitude range: -80 to -20
latitude range: -40 to +10

That is, most of South America extending into the Atlantic Ocean.

You could try to use the well-known text below. The ogr2ogr help page says that you can specify WKT or a file that contains WKT (the latter is easier) if there's no EPSG WKID.

```
PROJCS["Test_Sinusoidal",
GEOGCS["WGS_1984",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Some information is at [OSR Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/osr_tutorial.html).